PIL cannot set loop of GIF to 1
I am trying to convert a gif, first crop it then convert it into a gif which only loops once. It loops only once when I use Microsoft "Photo" app. However when on a html page it loops twice.
I've tried changing loop = 0, but it makes the loop become infinite.
This is the code I am using:
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
input_gif = "input.gif"
output_gif = "output.gif"

crop_box = (0, 0, 300, 500)  # (left, upper, right, lower)

with Image.open(input_gif) as gif:
    frames = []

    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(gif):
        cropped_frame = frame.crop(crop_box)
        frames.append(cropped_frame)

    frames[0].save(
        output_gif,
        save_all=True,
        append_images=frames[1:],
        loop=1,
        duration=gif.info.get("duration", 100),
    )

print("GIF cropped and saved successfully!")


I think you'll find the fault is with the web-browser, rather than PIL. A loop value of zero specifies infinite looping.

PIL's loop = 1 makes it loop twice in total, loop = 2 loops thrice, etc.
To get it to loop exactly once, remove the argument of loop completely, it defaults to once.
